Why is my MacBook Pro 2013 (15") new replacement fan noisy?
I just installed a new fan in my MacBook Pro (15" late 2013) and it’s significantly louder than the old one.
The new one is on the left, and the old one is on the right, the left one wore out (very noisy, flocked bearing), so I replaced it, but I notice the CPU is still hitting the +90 C zone so I'm wondering if I need to do the thermal paste as well.
Do laptop fans have a wear in period?
The paste I'm looking at is Grizzly Kryonaut.

Yes; Fans which are mechanical have a finite lifespan. I would say their lifespan is probably less than 10 years. The new fan being louder is probably expected since it’s either not designed for the form factor or faster than the original fan since you unlikely purchased a direct replacement. Thermal paste also has a lifespan

Fans do not have a wear in period.     Also, your pics did not make it to the site, so it somewhat limits us.

Without a sample of the sound we really can't say. That said, there is a difference between a good but loud fan, and a bad fan. You probably noted the roughness of the noise as your old fan was failing? That should be a good indicator of what a bad fan may sound like, allowing you to judge. It is possible a new fan is bad, but as others have noted, it could also simply be a louder fan.
